# Jquery Confirm isn't redirecting to the path after confirmed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a simple use case as I am new to jquery. After the task is confirmed as "Yes" Jquery confirm lib is not redirecting it to the url. Following is the case:

```
    <form action'' method='post' ><a href="/cancelforever">
 <span style="color:white;"><span id="changePassBtnText" >
Cancel</span></span></a></form>

<script>
$("#dataConfirm").confirm();
</script>
```

It pops up the window with message but when I click "Yes" to confirm the action it is not redirecting me to the url in link. Like on "/cancelforever".

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: No more code its a library with two js files to be included. https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm

Comment: wheres the code that does the redirect. If your using jQuery it's usually set up like `var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}`

Comment: This is the same piece of logic almost what I see in jquery library files. Can you please take a look at the link I've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code refers to an element with id `dataConfirm`, but we don't see that in your html. You probably just want to add this id to your `a` element.

```
<form action'' method='post' >
  <a id="dataConfirm" href="/cancelforever">
    <span style="color:white;">
      <span id="changePassBtnText" >Cancel</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</form>
```